# How to generate timeuuid in Jmeter beanshell processor?

Tags: java, cassandra, jmeter, load-testing

I would like to know a way to dynamically generate `timeUUID` via pre-processor or post-processor beanshell in Jmeter for dynamic load testing to better fit real life scenario.  I have tried to add datastax cassandra driver in `/lib` folder, but it seems to complain about missing `com.google.common.base.charsets` dependencies.  It is probably not a standalone cassandra driver.   Any suggestion for a library that can generate timeUUID would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into [Maven Central](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.cassandra/cassandra-driver-core/2.1.10.1) Cassandra JDBC Driver has some dependencies which you need to have in JMeter's CLASSPATH as well.

Example steps (assume [Apache Maven](https://maven.apache.org/))

1. Create an arbitrary folder somewhere
2. Create `pom.xml` file in that folder with the following contents:

   ```
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
       <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

       <groupId>gd.wa</groupId>
       <artifactId>minimal-pom</artifactId>
       <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
       <packaging>jar</packaging>

       <name>minimal-pom</name>
       <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

       <properties>
           <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
           <java.version>1.7</java.version>
       </properties>

       <build>
           <plugins>
               <plugin>
                   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                   <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                   <version>3.1</version>
                   <configuration>
                       <source>${java.version}</source>
                       <target>${java.version}</target>
                   </configuration>
               </plugin>
           </plugins>
       </build>

       <dependencies>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
               <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
               <version>2.1.10.1</version>
           </dependency>
       </dependencies>
   </project>
   ```
3. Replace `2.1.10.` with the version of your Cassandra server
4. In the folder created in step 1 execute the following command:

   ```
   mvn dependency:copy-dependencies
   ```
5. Copy all the .jar files from `target/dependency` folder to JMeter's CLASSPATH (i.e. to "lib" folder of your JMeter installation). My list looks like:

   ```
   asm-5.0.3.jar
   asm-analysis-5.0.3.jar
   asm-commons-5.0.3.jar
   asm-tree-5.0.3.jar
   asm-util-5.0.3.jar
   cassandra-driver-core-2.1.10.1.jar
   guava-14.0.1.jar
   jffi-1.2.10-native.jar
   jffi-1.2.10.jar
   jnr-constants-0.9.0.jar
   jnr-ffi-2.0.7.jar
   jnr-posix-3.0.27.jar
   jnr-x86asm-1.0.2.jar
   metrics-core-3.0.2.jar
   netty-buffer-4.0.33.Final.jar
   netty-codec-4.0.33.Final.jar
   netty-common-4.0.33.Final.jar
   netty-handler-4.0.33.Final.jar
   netty-transport-4.0.33.Final.jar
   slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
   ```
6. Restart JMeter to pick the jars up
7. In Beanshell Test Elements use the following code:

   ```
   import com.datastax.driver.core.utils.UUIDs;

   UUID timeUUID = UUIDs.timeBased();

   String timeUUIDString = timeUUID.toString();
   vars.put("timeUUID", timeUUIDString);
   //etc.
   ```

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) for more information on using Beanshell in JMeter.

Comment: Very detailed!! Thank you.  Wonder how did you come up with that pom.xml?

Comment: It's just a minimal POM file + cassandra driver dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably need to put also the guava jar file into `/lib`

Look at the source code of **[UUIDS](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/3.0/driver-core/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/core/utils/UUIDs.java)** class, it is importing `com.google.common.base.charsets`